# How to join in NHibernate/Fluent?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

This is so simple that I bet this has to be a duplicate question.

I have `Dog` and `Cat`, which are mapped to tables:

```
class Dog
{
    public virtual long Id;
    public virtual long catId;
}

class Cat
{
    public virtual long Id;
    public virtual string Name;
}
```

What I want is to obtain every Dog with Cat's name, instead of the id:

```
class DogWithName
{
    public virtual long Id;
    public virtual string CatName;
}
```

So `DogWithName` should be the result of a `Dog` and `Cat` joined query. I thought about creating a mapping for `DogWithName`, but that means that a `DogWithName` table will be created in the schema.

I don't want that. I only want a dynamic query that returns every Dog with the referenced Cat's name. How should I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var result = from d in Session.Query<Dogs>() select new DogWithName { Id = d.Id, CatName = d.Cat.Name }
```

You have to map your classes though.  The mappings are what define the way the tables are joined.

I'd also change your Dog class to

```
public class Dog
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Cat Cat { get; set; }
}
```

you then need to map the Cat as a ManyToOne relationship.  You haven't provided any mappings?

Comment: I was trying to avoid mapping the relationship fearing that the full object would be retrieved, but now I know that it wouldn't work that way with NHibernate, and I would have to write everything in pure SQL or HQL. Thanks.